# State is null, after useEffect hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to set product by dispatching a method in a useEffect. However, state still says null.

index.html

```
import React, { useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import { fetchProductsData } from "../../store/products-actions";

import Promotion from "./components/Promotion";
import Products from "./components/Products";
import ToastUi from "../../shared/ui/ToastUi";

import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // const products = useSelector((state) => state.products.products);
  const products = useSelector((state) => state.products.productsTest);
  const cartQuantity = useSelector((state) => state.cart.quantity);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProductsData());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <ToastUi
        status="Sukses"
        title="Notifikasi"
        message={`(${cartQuantity}) produk baru berhasil di masukkan keranjang`}
      />
      <Container fluid="xl">
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Promotion />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row className="mt-3" md={3}>
          <Products products={products} />
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Products still says null after a cycle, apparently it needs second cycle to make that state changed. Not sure how can I make it change in one cycle. Do I need to put the useEffect in the parent ?

**EDIT**
if I add this, it will work

```
 {products !== null && <Products products={products} />}
 // {/* <Products products={products} /> */} //
```

However, is there a better way or maybe some explanation on why this is happening, Thank you.

**EDIT**

products-slice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import {
  products,
  excel_products,
  product,
  filteredProducts,
  productsTest,
} from "../datafiles";

const initialProductsState = {
  products,
  excel_products,
  product,
  filteredProducts,
  productsTest,
};

const productsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState: initialProductsState,
  reducers: {
    viewExcelProducts(state, action) {
      state.excel_products = action.payload;
    },
    uploadExcelProducts(state) {
      if (excel_products.length < 0) {
        console.log("error");
      } else {
        const newProducts = state.products.concat(state.excel_products);
        state.products = newProducts;
        state.excel_products = [];
      }
    },
    selectProduct(state, action) {
      const product = state.products.find((item) => item.id === action.payload);
      state.product = product;
    },
    filterProducts(state, action) {
      const filteredProducts = state.products.filter(
        (item) => item.type === action.payload
      );
      state.filteredProducts = filteredProducts;
    },
    setProducts(state, action) {
      state.productsTest = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const productsActions = productsSlice.actions;
export default productsSlice;
```

products-actions.js

```
import { productsActions } from "./products-slice";

export const fetchProductsData = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/products");

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Could not fetch data!");
      }
      const data = await response.json();

      return data;
    };
    try {
      const productsData = await fetchData();
      dispatch(productsActions.setProducts(productsData));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error: " + err);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you show `fetchProductsData` action implementation?

Comment: there are not enough information in your question, what is the `products` state value after your fetchProductsData executed? If you put a `console.log(products)` before `return` to capture the last value, and post it here, it may help

Comment: Sure, I've added the code on my second edit statement above.

Also, when I console log it , it produce 2 different log, one is null then the on the second log the value changes as I wanted to be which is an array of object

Comment: since you mentioned check `products !== null` and display `Products`, I think it should be something related to the `products` value or some login wrong in `Products`. could you also post the `Products` component to have a look?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. When using hooks useEffect to fetch data from api, the data is null when the page renders. As soon as I click on anything that causes a re-render, the data comes up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by `it needs second cycle to make that state changed`?

`fetchProductsData` is an async function, I assume. That means that you do not receive data immediately, but after some time (depending on network connection speed, payload size etc). So it is OK that your data arrives later.

Usual approach for async data is to keep `isLoading` in your state. And use it as following:

```js
  const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state.products.isLoading);
  ...
  return (
    <Fragment>
      ...
      {isLoading && <Spinner />} // Some loading indicator
      {!isLoading && <Products products={products} />}
    </Fragment>
  );
```

This way you will indicate to user that some data is being fetched. This is a good UX approach.

`isLoading` should be set somewhere in your `fetchProductsData` action, like so:

```js
export const fetchProductsData = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    ...
    try {
      dispatch(productsActions.setIsLoading(true));
      const productsData = await fetchData();
      dispatch(productsActions.setProducts(productsData));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error: " + err);
    } finally {
      dispatch(productsActions.setIsLoading(false));
    }
  };
};
```